Read Date from excel and insert into PostgreSQL
I have problem while reading date from Excel file using Apache Poi.
I use the following:
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFilePath);

Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = firstSheet.iterator();

Cell nextCell = cellIterator.next();
Date testTimestamp = nextCell.getDateCellValue();

This lead me to ERROR:

Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell

Column in Excel is type of General (I tried also Date, Time, Text, Number).
Value in this column is like: 2023-10-11 13:20:43.000

Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Apache POI supports it: use Cell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue() to get a LocalDateTime from your Excel cell. The Date class had design problems and has been outdated the last 10 years.

Are you quite sure the cell you think does indeed contain a date/time?  It can be confusing when using an interface like Excel.
For example if you type 3 into a cell in Excel, Excel guesses you are entering a number and stores it as a number.  But if you prefix the number with a quote, so you type '3 then it looks the same but the data is now stored as a String (and by the way, the default is that strings are left-ranged, numbers are right ranged).
The same happens with Date/Times.  You might think you are looking at a date time but you might be looking at a String.  My guess is that you have this problem
I would do these things:

from your java program, print the type for the cell with nextCell.getCellType().  A Date time will be of CellType.NUMERIC and not CellType.STRING (note that there is no CellType.DATETIME)
print the output from your java program.  If you get a integer/float, then this is good, if it is a String like "2023-10-11 13:20:43.000" then you have a problem in your Spreadsheet...
Open the source file in Excel and check the cell you are expecting to be a Date Time.  If Excel understands it to be a Date/Time, then if you change the format of the cell (cosmetically) using Format Menu > Cell> Category > Date then if you can vary the format from say displaying from "2023-10-11 13:20:43.000" to "11 October 2023" then it is correctly a date time.  If Excel won't reformat it, then it thinks it is a string and there is your problem.


Thank you for answer @AndrewL
You are right with everything you wrote.

getCellType() return String
Printed value is: "2023-10-11 13:20:43.000"
I tried to format cell to date but excel does not do that

Can I use for example CSV instead? It would be better? I just have some amount of data (currently in excel) and I need to insert it, do some transformation in DB and prepare autmatic tests to check results. It does not matter whether I will use excel or not.

So you have closed in on your problem, it is not a Apache POI/Java problem, but the source.  Find a tutorial like this https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time#_Toc495931393 to see how to enter date/times in Excel.  But if your source of data is not entered by hand but a CSV, then stop using Apache POI and use any CSV parser.  e.g. https://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html or Jackson see https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/reading-csv-with-jackson-c4e74a15ddc1

Data I use was entered by hand. Well to be precise it was coppied from dBeaver from result of queries and paste to excel. I can just change it to CSV it that help. Anyway, thank you for your comments. I will check the tutorial and if still have problems I will switch approach to use CSV. Will add comment with results later. Have a great day :)
